# Signal not triggering slot in Qt when emitting the signal from closeEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application where I have a Client class that emits a closed signal when the close event occurs. I have properly declared and connected the signal and slot in the Client and Window1 classes respectively, but the slot is not being triggered as expected.

Here is the relevant code snippet from the Client class:

```
void Client::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    emit closed(); // Emitting the closed signal
    qDebug() << "Client::closeEvent invoked";
}
```

In my Window1 class, I have connected the closed signal from the Client object to the onClientClosed slot using the following line:

```
connect(client, &Client::closed, this, &Window1::onClientClosed);
```

I have verified the connection code and the object's lifecycle, ensuring they are correct. However, when the close event occurs, the slot onClientClosed is not triggered.

I have also tried other approaches, such as using the deleteLater() function, but the issue persists. I suspect there might be some other factor preventing the slot from being triggered.

Could someone please help me understand why the emitted signal is not working as expected in the close event? Are there any other possible reasons for the slot not being triggered?

Thank you for any guidance or assistance you can provide.

Comment: So, are you seeing the qDebug() output when you expect it? If so, can you put a similar statement in your slot?

Comment: Is client in the same thread as Window1

Comment: yes,they are in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

I know what's wrong with it.beacause I m not clear about the `connect` function.
i thought the `connect`in the constructor will connect the signal and slot forever.but I changed the sender pointer, so the previous connection is not usable.